# Problema al querer enviar un formulario con una lista de objetos por thymeleaf al controlador

Tags: java, mysql, spring, thymeleaf

espero que me puedan ayudar. Me sale el siguiente error cuando intento pasar una lista por formulario en el thymeleaf. Alguien podrá ayudarme?

Cannot invoke "java.util.List.iterator()" because the return value of "dtos.PasarLista.getAlumnos()" is null

```
<form th:action="@{/asistencia/guardar}" th:object="${pasarLista}"
                    method="post">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Apellido y Nombre</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Presentismo</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Observaciones</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr th:each="al:${pasarLista.alumnos}">
                                    <td th:text="${al.getAlumnoNombre()}">
                                    <td><div class="form-check ">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" checked>
                                        </div></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <button type="submit" th:href="@{/administrador/}"
                            class="btn btn-outline-success">Guardar Asistencia</button>
                </form>
```

---

Controlador

```
@PostMapping("/guardar")
    public String guardarAsistencia(@ModelAttribute("pasarLista") PasarLista pasarLista, Model model){
        
        Curso curso = cursoService.buscarCursoPorId(pasarLista.getCurso().getId());
        Materia materia = materiaService.buscarMateriaPorId(pasarLista.getMateria().getId());

        for (AlumnoAsistenciaDto a : pasarLista.getAlumnos()) {
            Asistencia asistencia = new Asistencia();
```

Comment: y el siguiente error es????

Comment: Ahí lo acomodé, me sucede que al llamar al getAlumnos() en el controlador me devuelve null y ya no se como hacer para pasar la lista que si tengo en el objeto de thymeleaf